# Celery worker is not starting for my django project hosted on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, celery, amazon-sqs

[error in the eb console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdecn.png)Good day by co-developers.

I have a project working on aws elasticbeanstalk and i want to integerate celery to it but the celery worker is not starting and everything is workking fine in development but when i deploy it to elastic ebeanstalk it wont start the worker. my question is that is there any way to start the celery worker or i am during it wrong.

below is my Procfile file where i start it with the error i am getting the coonsoole and the log in the instance.
thanks in advance.

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn --timeout 90 ayjayproject.wsgi
celery_beat: celery -A ayjayproject.celery beat -l INFO 
celery_worker: celery -A ayjayproject.celery worker -l INFO -P solo
```

Log fiile

```
2023/10/23 10:35:00.909620 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf celery_beat.service
2023/10/23 10:35:00.919175 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active celery_beat.service
2023/10/23 10:35:00.927731 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start celery_beat.service
2023/10/23 10:35:00.958395 [INFO] Registering the proc: celery_worker

2023/10/23 10:35:00.958424 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf celery_worker.service
2023/10/23 10:35:00.975817 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2023/10/23 10:35:01.145963 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2023/10/23 10:35:01.159697 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-enabled eb-app.target
2023/10/23 10:35:01.171728 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable eb-app.target
2023/10/23 10:35:01.360203 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start eb-app.target
2023/10/23 10:35:01.376355 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable celery_worker.service
2023/10/23 10:35:01.556311 [INFO] Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/celery_worker.service to /etc/systemd/system/celery_worker.service.

2023/10/23 10:35:01.556349 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf celery_worker.service
2023/10/23 10:35:01.567417 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active celery_worker.service
2023/10/23 10:35:01.583871 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start celery_worker.service
2023/10/23 10:35:01.622278 [INFO] Executing instruction: start X-Ray
2023/10/23 10:35:01.622299 [INFO] X-Ray is not enabled.
2023/10/23 10:35:01.622305 [INFO] Executing instruction: start proxy with new configuration
2023/10/23 10:35:01.622333 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf
2023/10/23 10:35:01.659000 [INFO] nginx: the configuration file /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

2023/10/23 10:35:01.659261 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c cp -rp /var/proxy/staging/nginx/* /etc/nginx
2023/10/23 10:35:01.676367 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2023/10/23 10:35:01.700445 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2023/10/23 10:35:01.908821 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2023/10/23 10:35:01.920569 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2023/10/23 10:35:01.941971 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active nginx.service
2023/10/23 10:35:01.959767 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start nginx.service
2023/10/23 10:35:02.098201 [INFO] Executing instruction: configureSqsd
2023/10/23 10:35:02.098224 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip configure sqsd daemon ...
2023/10/23 10:35:02.098229 [INFO] Executing instruction: startSqsd
2023/10/23 10:35:02.098233 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip start sqsd daemon ...
2023/10/23 10:35:02.098238 [INFO] Executing instruction: Track pids in healthd
2023/10/23 10:35:02.098243 [INFO] This is an enhanced health env...
2023/10/23 10:35:02.098265 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf aws-eb.target | cut -d= -f2
2023/10/23 10:35:02.120632 [INFO] cfn-hup.service healthd.service nginx.service

2023/10/23 10:35:02.120666 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf eb-app.target | cut -d= -f2
2023/10/23 10:35:02.139210 [INFO] celery_worker.service web.service celery_beat.service

2023/10/23 10:35:02.139459 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks
2023/10/23 10:35:02.139474 [INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/postdeploy/
2023/10/23 10:35:02.139500 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ does not exist
2023/10/23 10:35:02.139505 [INFO] Finished running scripts in /var/app/current/.platform/hooks/postdeploy
2023/10/23 10:35:02.139512 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2023/10/23 10:35:02.139617 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"Engine execution has succeeded.","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment successfully used commands in the 'Procfile' to start your application.","timestamp":1698057297415,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment completed successfully.","timestamp":1698057302139,"severity":"INFO"}]}]}
```

Is this not the way to start a celery worker?

Please help me with other way i can do that.

Comment: Hi, I cant see any errors in logs. What made you think that celery is not working?

Comment: @VladMarchenko because what is being display in the environmment console: Following services are not running: celery_worker.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have a django project which i deploy on eb and when i add the celery to the django project i deloy it to the eb, the celery worker i added to the procfiile is not starting the worker. so all i need now is that is there any way i can start the worker except adding it to the procfile.